# Por que no puedo ver una parte de la pagina web despues de una redireccion de dominio

Tags: php, laravel-5

Trabajo con una plataforma escolar con laravel. Pero hay una parte de la pagina donde debería poder asignar docentes a grupos y ya no me aparece. Ya revise el código y parece estar bien. El error comenzó desde que hice la redirección de la carpeta raíz a una subcarpeta como pagina principal.

```
 {!! Form::open(['url'=> '/admin/usuariosasignar','method'=>'POST',
                                                'files' => true,'role'=>'form','class'=>'']) !!}
                                  <div>
                                    <label for="materia">Asignar Usuario a Grupo</label>
                                  </div>
                                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                      <input type="hidden" name="caso" value="asignar">
                                      <input type="hidden" name="idg" value="{{$g->id}}">
<select class="form-control" name="materia" id="materia">
                                     @foreach($usuarios as $usu)
<?php $bol=false;?>
@foreach($inscritos as $inscri)
                                        @if($inscri->id_usuario==$usu->id AND $usu->nivel=='alumno')
                                          <?php $bol=true;?>
                                        @endif
                                      @endforeach
@if($bol==false)
                                         <option value="{{$usu->id}}">{{$usu->nombre}} {{$usu->apellidos}}</option>
                                      @endif
@endforeach
</select>
<span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button class="btn btn-bordered btn-flat" type="submit" id="gen1">Asignar</button>
                                      </span>
                                    </div><!-- /input-group -->
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este código esta previamente para dar un poco mas de contexto.

```
   @else
             @foreach($inscritos as $usuario1)
             @if(Auth::user()->id==$usuario1->id_usuario AND $usuario1->id_grupo==$g->id)
    <div class="box box-default collapsed-box">
    <div class="box-header with-border">
    <h3 class="box-title" data-widget="collapse">{{$g->grupo}}</h3><div class="box-tools pull-right">
    <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                  </div><!-- /.box-tools -->
                </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                <div class="box-body">
                   <table class="table">
                            <tr>
                              <th style="width: 10px">#</th>
                              <th>Usuario</th>
                              <th style="width: 40px"></th>
                            </tr>
                              @foreach($inscritos as $usuario)
                                @if($usuario->id_grupo==$g->id)
                                <tr>
                                  <td>{{$x}}.</td>
                                  <td>{{$usuario->nombre}} {{$usuario->apellidos}}</td>
                                  <td>
                                  <span class="badge bg-navy">
                                      <button style="color:white;background:transparent;border:none"
                                          data-toggle="modal"
                                          data-idgrupo="{{$g->id}}"
                                          data-target="#editarmodal"
                                          class="editar"
                                          data-id="{{$usuario->id}}"
                                          data-idusuario="{{$usuario->id_usuario}}"
                                          data-nombre="{{$usuario->nombre}}"
                                          data-apellidos="{{$usuario->apellidos}}"
                                          data-telefono="{{$usuario->telefono}}"
                                           data-email="{{$usuario->email}}"
                                          >Editar</a>
                                  </span>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php $x++;?>
                                @endif
                            @endforeach
                    </table>
```

Me pueden orientar para saber donde podría estar el error. Gracias

Comment: Al mirar el código no me queda claro cuál es la porción que debería aparecer y no aparece.

Comment: Hola Shaz, lo que debe aparecer es un label que dice asignar usuario a grupo (justo donde puse el rectángulo rojo o al final de la lista de cada grupo.) y se despliega una lista con todos los usuarios registrados en la base de datos.

Comment: Necesitamos ver más contexto para poder ayudar, qué código hay antes? ¿hay algún condicional? qué muestra un `dump($usuarios)` y un  `dump($inscritos)`?

Answer (score 0):

Cuando haces cambios de ruta tienes que asegurarte de que los recursos están disponible en la nueva carpeta, o indicar que los recursos están en la carpeta anterior.

Ejemplo;

**Carpeta /home/hamza/pagina-manolito** > Contiene los siguientes archivos: *index.html*, *foto_manolo.png*

Archivo *index.html*

```
<h1>Hola, jejoju </h1>
<h2>Buena fuente, mala gente</h2>
<img src="foto_manolo.png"/>
```

**Ahora migramos nuestra página a  /home/hamza/pagina-manolito/manolito_nuevo** > Contiene los siguientes archivos: *index.html*

Archivo *index.html*

```
<h1>Hola, jejoju </h1>
<h2>Buena fuente, mala gente</h2>
<img src="../foto_manolo.png"/><!-- LE INDICAMOS QUE LA FOTO ESTA EN LA CARPETA ANTERIOR CON `../`, SI NO EL PROGRAMA INTENTA CARGAR LA FOTO EN LA RUTA ACTUAL, PERO NO EXISTE
```

Si no le especificamos la ruta de la imagen, el busca en la ruta actual (donde no existe), al no existir no puede mostrar la imagen.

En tu caso puede estar buscando `/admin/usuariosasignar` cuando es `../admin/usuariosasignar`, estos problemas se evitan utilizando la ruta absoluta (aunque pierdes las ventajas que ofrece no utilizar la ruta absoluta).

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Ya hice los cambios que me indicaste pero aun sin éxito, no se ve la opción. Habrá algo mas que tengo que indicar?